# A problem occurred evaluating root project 'audioplayers'. Failed to apply plugin [id 'kotlin-android'] in Flutter Project

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, audio-streaming

When I create "flutter build apk" in my project I get an error like this:

*** What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'audioplayers'.

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'kotlin-android']
> The current Gradle version 4.10.2 is not compatible with the Kotlin Gradle plugin. Please use Gradle 5.3 or newer, or the previous version of the Kotlin plugin.
> **

[image: Error project]

In this project, I'm using audioplayers: ^0.19.1 package. But when I run this project as usual "flutter run --verbose". successful..
in this case, I can't build apk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error suggests, upgrade your gradle version.

Are you using the gradle wrapper?
then find the file:

`gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` and update the version in the distro url to for instance `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.1.1-bin.zip`

edit: note that if you bump up by a few major version you might run into some deprecation issues. You could also go for version 5.3 which is the minimum your error suggests.
if you are using the globally installed gradle version, upgrade that with whatever system you installed it.

Comment: I have updated the version in the distro url to distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.1.1-bin.zip, but still not working.. the error message same as previous @p.streef

Comment: then you are not using the gradle wrapper. How exactly are you building?

Comment: I think so sir. In my project, there is an audioplayers package and when i build apk it reads gradle in audioplayers, not reads gradle in root of my project. What is the solution sir? @p.streef

Comment: it does not "read gradle" it excecutes tasks, now the question is how are they executed. for that I would like to know exactly how you trigger the build. Are you calling a command in terminal? If so, what is the command? Are you pressing a button in an IDE? Which button in which IDE?

Comment: I'm using this command in terminal, for build apk sir. 
"flutter build apk --split-per-abi --no-sound-null-safety" @p.streef

Comment: Oke, perfect sir. Done,,,, After I'm updated gradle-wrapper.properties, gradle plugin version, kotlin version, audioplayers package and auto_orientation package. Thank you very much sir. @p.streef

Comment: I believe this was fixed in version 0.19.1 of the Audioplayers package.